# Nesting multiple OR conditions in BIRT

Tags: javascript, birt

Have been experimenting here with some BIRT reports, and found something interesting,

I want to show a hidden element if the location is different than the ones listed in the expression.
Have been playing with it for a while and found that the following expressions do not work:

```
row["location"] != "Loc1" || row["location"] != "Loc2" || row["location"] != "Loc3"  || row["location"] != "Loc4"
```

Also not working:

```
row["location"] != "Loc1" || "Loc2" || "Loc3"  || "Loc4"
```

If I try however:

```
row["location"] != "Loc1" || row["location"] != "Loc2"
```

The expression works for Loc1, but not Loc2. This is also the case if the expression is formed like this:

```
row["location"] != "Loc1" || "Loc2"
```

Does anyone have any idea what is the correct strategy to perform this expression with multiple OR evaluations in BIRT?

The normal javascript expressions such as 
    if (row["location"] !== "Loc1" && row["location"] !== "Loc1" && row["location"] !== "Loc1")

Do not work either. The documentation also does not provide any significant clues on how to solve this.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want AND, as in `&&`, it seems unlikely that the value is not something OR not something, makes more sense that it's not something AND not something else.

Comment: As a sidenote `["Loc1", "Loc2", "Loc3", "Loc4"].indexOf(row["location"]) != -1`

Comment: Thanks Adeneo! Very elegant sidenote. Also changing the operator to && will do the job.

Comment: @adeneo you should post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted and this will not look like a question still needing an answer

Comment: @adeneo: post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted an this question is displayed as solved.